# Android Button Alignment

Tags: android, tablelayout, xmltable

I've did my due diligence in searching the net but I can't seem to find a proper solution for the following.

I'm using a table layout and a table row and I am putting in 3 buttons with TEXT. Here is a sample of the layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tlRemoteTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ABCD" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ABCDEFGHI" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

The image outcome is here:

[image: Uneven Layout]

My aim is the make it even, all having 1/3 ratio. I understand that the text length is the one that is forcing it to expand. How can I wrap the text instead?

The ultimate outcome will be a dynamically generated file. So I'll be programming it, instead of XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tlRemoteTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0f">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ABCD" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ABCDEFGHI" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

you can change button width to 0dp all set is's working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! That worked!

Here's the programatic codes if anyone needs it!

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams trParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
TableRow.LayoutParams btnParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```